# Integration as a Continuous Linear Map

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

Let $X$ be a compactly generated topological space, and put $\text{Top}(X, \mathbb{R})$ for the algebra of continuous real valued functions on $X$.

An integral (induced by a measure) is a continuous linear map $\int : \text{Top}(X, \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Does this axiomatize integrals? Is there a reference for this perspective on measure theory? Thanks very much!

Comment: What is a "compactly generated" topological space?

Comment: If $X$ is nice enough, and supposed that *signed measures* are also enabled, then yes. Roughly, for every open set $A$, consider a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ whose limit is the characteristic function $1_A$ of $A$, so that we can define $\mu(A) :=\lim T(f_n)$..

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Nice to meet you, professor Ullrich. I am a fan of your textbook, complex made simple. A space $X$ is compactly generated when $X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous if and only if $K \rightarrow X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous for each compact hausdorff space $K$. The upshot is that compactly generated spaces form a convenient category of topological spaces. The condition is not important here now that I think about it. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Berci I think I understand what you're saying. I was hoping someone had a reference for it too.

Comment: I don't follow that definition at all - probably not your fault, I'm not used to anything "categorical". If $X$ is locally compact then the Riesz Representation Theorem is what you're looking for.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks so much for the reference. Don't sweat it about the definition, it may never come up for you again. For future reference, Algebraic topologists wanted a sub-category of topological spaces with better properties. The main problem was that Top(X, Y) can't always be made into a topological space in a sensible way, since it is not adjoint to product always. This is the most common property to put on a topological space so that can happen. It's a pretty weak condition, but strong enough to put good properties on the corresponding category.